# Ninject Singleton binding in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, singleton, ninject

When using Singleton scope in an MVC application, would other threads be blocked from accessing my singleton object while one thread is already calling a method on it?

Eg: I have a repository that is bound in singleton scope. If multiple users visit a page that uses the repository to fetch data off the database, does it mean that the until the first thread that acquired the singleton instance is finished doing its work, the second thread cannot obtain the singleton instance?

In which case, if my repository takes 2 - 3 seconds to load up data from the db, does it mean the other thread is waiting to obtain this singleton object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ninject only makes sure that everyone gets the same object. Handling concurrent access to the object is your (or the object's implementation) responsiblity.

However, if the singleton's constructor takes a long time, it will take a long time to instanciate the first object where the singleton will be injected as constructor argument.

It is generally inadvisable to have costly (long-running) code in the constructor.